# Do you have to manually rotate your app when orientation changes or does Expo handle it by default?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo / React Native and I havn't done anything with orientation.

When I rotate a device the app doesn't rotate. Is this not handled by default or do I have a bug?

From the docs it seems you can set the orientation and respond to orientation change events: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/

Do I have to manually set the orientation of the app when I detect the orientation has changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the orientation was set in the app.json. Removing this line makes it work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can also set the orientation to default on your app.json instead of removing it, like this:

```
"orientation": "default"
```

Note: Make sure you **restart your expo server/bundler** (by pressing `r` on your terminal) and **then close and reopen the Expo Go app** on your simulator/real device **to see the effect of these changes**.